# K8s: Unable to curl to POD ID

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am new to Kubernetes and trying out few things on my local machine using minikube.
I created a new pod using
`kubectl run apache --image=httpd:2.2`

and when i do `get pod`, i see the pod up and running

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apache-6dbf894fbc-kc5d8   1/1     Running   0          33m
```

When I describe the pod, I see the pod's IP as well

```
kubectl get pod apache-6dbf894fbc-kc5d8 -o yaml
...
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://b05ca94634b40595b83fcd08bab4c8f3f055dbf5fe821708f72ea464cf758eb4
    image: httpd:2.2
    imageID: docker-pullable://httpd@sha256:9784d70c8ea466fabd52b0bc8cde84980324f9612380d22fbad2151df9a430eb
    lastState: {}
    name: apache
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2020-08-21T15:42:38Z"
  hostIP: 172.17.0.2
  phase: Running
  podIP: 172.18.0.3
  podIPs:
  - ip: 172.18.0.3
```

I believe I should be able to curl to this port, but the  operation times out

```
curl -I 172.18.0.3
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80: Operation timed out
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. In one of the docs I am going through, it shows that we should be able to curl.

```
PIP=$(kubectl get pod apache -o jsonpath='{.status.podIP}') && echo $PIP 10.32.0.4
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-67:~$

ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-67:~$ curl -I $PIP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 20:05:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.1t DAV/2 Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Nov 2004 20:16:24 GMT
ETag: "c0050-2c-3e9564c23b600"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 44
Content-Type: text/html
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-67:~$
```

Also, when I do `docker container ls`, I cannot see this container. Again, I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First exec into pod using `kubectl exec -it pod_name -- /bin/sh` and then do `curl POD_IP:port`

Then you should see the result.

Comment: Then I believe need to install curl in the pod. Shouldn't I be able to curl from outside. The doc I am reading does not specify anything like that. Also, shouldn't the container be present when I do `docker container ls`

Comment: @CSUNNY No because the pod IP is not exposed to outside world. it is internal inside cluster.

Comment: and Yes you have to install curl inside pod.